# Security for data obtained from the database

Tags: php, wp-query, functions, options

I am getting information from the database to show it to the user, example:

```
$data = (get_option('config')) ? get_option('config') : false;
```

I need to display this data when loading the webpage, example:

```
<label><?php echo $data['title']; ?></label>
<input type="text" value=" <?php echo $data['value']; ?> " >
```

Is it necessary protect this data before showing it to the user, if the information is obtained from the database?

*Thank you very much*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it depends on the context. Usually we don't need to protect data for only showing it in frontend. ***But the best practice is, always escape or validate data, no matter where they comes from.*** Like for your case you can do that like below-

```
<label><?php echo esc_html( $data['title'] ); ?></label>
<input type="text" value=" <?php echo esc_attr( $data['value'] ); ?> " >
```

Hope this above helps.

Comment: That’s not a string in that translate function. It’s a variable. Variables [shouldn’t be used](http://ottopress.com/2012/internationalization-youre-probably-doing-it-wrong/) in translate functions.

Comment: Uha... I didn't notice that ! Thanks ! @JacobPeattie I'll change my answer !